# Lua - explanation of the example of nested loops

Tags: lua

I'm learning some basics of lua for a few days but I have a problem of understanding the example of nested loops from(https://www.tutorialspoint.com/lua/lua_nested_loops.htm)

```
j = 2
for i = 2,10 do
   for j = 2,(i/j) , 2 do
    
      if(not(i%j)) 
      then
         break 
      end
        
      if(j > (i/j))then
         print("Value of i is",i)
      end
        
   end
end
```

I think I know the uses of the syntax but I need some explanation of the whole code because I don't really understand that what is the code for and how it works.

Comment: Hm, i tested above code and it seems the only number for j that makes sense is 2 - So here is my oneliner: ```do local j=2 for i=j,j*5 do for j=j,(i/j),j do if not (i%j) then break end if j>(i/j) then print('Value of i is',i) end end end end```

Answer (score 0):

A nested for loop is just a for loop inside another for loop. You do this if you want to run a for loop in every cycle of another for loop. There is not much more to explain.

The code is just a random example of such a nested for loop. You don't have to understand what it is used for. It just prints a few numbers.

Personally. I don't like such non-sense examples.

It doesn't make much sense anyway. Somewone who knows Lua wouldn't write do something like `if(not(i%j)`.

a) you don't need parenthesis here

b) `i%j` is always an integer so `not(i%j)` will always be false regardless of `i` and `j`'s values.

If you understand how a for loop works, you'll know what happens in a nested for loop.